# Windows Phone 8, how to convert an image to .png?

Tags: image, image-manipulation, windows-phone-8

For Windows Phone 8 (and I'm assuming it will be similar for Windows 8), how does one convert any image they get to .png?

For example, I get a .jpeg or .gif and I convert it to .png.

Would also be interested in maybe turning a .png to .jpeg.

I would prefer built in methods before third party applications.

Thank you!

Comment: Please note that tags stand alone and can not be combined to create new terms.  For example, combining `windows` and `phone` doesn't mean you're talking about Windows Phone.

Answer (score 3):

There are no built-in features in WP7/WP8 to convert from JPG to PNG.

One good 3rd party framework to use if all you need is to save WriteableBitmap as JPEG is [ToolStack C# PNG Writer Library](http://toolstack.com/libraries/pngwriter).

```
var myBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(tempBitmap);

// Create the destitnation stream.
var pngDest = new System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFileStream("test.png", FileMode.Create, isoStore);

// use the WriteableBitmap extension to write out the PNG
myBitmap.WritePNG(pngDest);
```

If you need a more fully featured toolset (such as loading JPG) check out [WriteableBitmapEx](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) and this great article by Rene Schulte @ [Convert, Encode And Decode Silverlight WriteableBitmap Data](http://kodierer.blogspot.com/2009/11/convert-encode-and-decode-silverlight.html)

Comment: What do you think of imageTools? http://imagetools.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Working%20with%20different%20image%20formats&referringTitle=Home

I see this one hasn't been updated in awhile so I'm not sure it would work on WP8 but it also gives bmp which WriteableBitmapEx doesn't seem to give.

Comment: I'm pretty sure ImageTools for WP7 doesn't support one of those formats... either JPG or PNG. Try to use it and it fails at runtime.

Comment: Ok I'll look into WriteableBitmapEx when I get home and see how that works. Is there anything that can convert to .bmp as well? I'm trying to cover as much image conversion I can on the phone without the need of a webservice.

Answer (score -1):

One thing to consider is to use a program outside your app to convert your images.

I use paint or gimp.  You can download gimp for free and it is a good program.

Here is a place to start:

http://www.gimp.org/