# Windows Phone generating Tile - cant seem to make it transparent

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am generating a tile from within my application and when its displayed the background image that its using as the basis fro the the tile has lost its transparency (and therefore its not picking up the theme color.

The background image has an icon on it and is transparent - when I use it as the standard Tile (i.e. not generate an image with it ) thens its fine and the transparency is all good..

But when I use it as the background image and add my own container over it then its not transparent the background is showing as black.

The relevant code is as follows:

```
    // [...]
    var container = new Grid(); 

    if (isWide)
    {     
        container = CreateContainerWide(tileInfo);
    }
    else
    {
        container = CreateContainerMedium(tileInfo);
    }

    // Add the background
    container.Background = new ImageBrush
    {
        ImageSource = background,
        Opacity = opacity
    };

    // Force the container to render itself
    container.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, width, height));

    // Write the image to disk and return the filename
    return WriteShellTileUIElementToDisk(container, baseFileName);
}

static string WriteShellTileUIElementToDisk(UIElement element, string baseFileName)
{
    var wb = new WriteableBitmap(element, null);

    // All content must be in this sub-folder of IsoStore
    string fileName = SharedImagePath + baseFileName + ImageExtension;
    var stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(fileName, System.IO.FileMode.Create, Isf);

    // Write the JPEG using the standard tile size
    // Sometimes the bitmap has (0,0) size and this fails for unknown reasons with an argument exception
    if (wb.PixelHeight > 0)
        wb.SaveJpeg(stream, wb.PixelWidth, wb.PixelHeight, 0, JpegQuality);
    else
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Can't write out file because bitmap had 0,0 size; not sure why");
        // indicate that there is an issue
        fileName = null;
    }

    stream.Close();

    // Return the filename
    return fileName;
}
```

Doesn't seem to make any difference as to what I set the Opacity of the ImageBrush to.

If I used a solid color rataher than a transparent layer then its all fine.  Somehow the creation of the png is losing the transparency.

Any Ideas?

- thanks

Comment: Ok.. I am  creating a JPEG and this will not save the transparency...

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14026559/2332193) might be helpful. Instead of saving a JPG you can save the image as a PNG which does support transparency. [The library](http://toolstack.com/libraries/pngwriter) mentioned in the answer is quite useful.